# What was the reason for auto-assigning bounty to an unhelpful answer?

Tags: support, bounty

I posted a question on SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44028674/visual-studio-can-reference-win8-1-project-from-net4-5-test-project)) regarding Windows app project management in Visual Studio. I anticipated that the question would be a tough one as I found nothing helpful when I was researching the issue before posting the question.

After the requisite waiting period, I posted a bounty of 100 rep to get some more attention. I had some interesting suggestions in the comments which I tried, but didn't solve the problem. In the last 24 hours of the bounty, an answer was posted, and in a very short time was upvoted twice. It seemed to me to be a stab in the dark. But I gave it a shot, and it was not successful, and I noted that in the comments on the answer.

Now that my bounty has expired, the SO system auto-assigned 50 of my rep to that answer because, according to the help docs, it had at least 2 upvotes.

I am confused as to why the 1/2-bounty was auto-assigned, and concerned that people that may be following up on the question will think that the answer was correct because the bounty is assigned to it. In truth, the person that was working with me in the question comments provided much more valuable advice than the suggested answer did.

I am looking for help understanding why this auto-assign system is in place, and what is my recourse to draw attention to this question now that my initial bounty has expired.

Comment: To draw attention to it, you can add another bounty. Note that it will need to be at least 200 reputation, though.

Comment: @zondo Interesting.. still might be worth it though.. unless someone still doesn't provide a helpful answer.. does the unhelpful answer get half of the new bounty too??

Comment: I believe it would.

Comment: @jwatts Only answers posted after the bounty was created are eligible for automatic awards.

Comment: @animuson Ok. I had no traction on the question for 8 to 9 days.. the answer in question popped up in the last day of the bounty.

Comment: @jwatts1980: "the answer in question popped up in the last day of the bounty" Which answers to bountied questions usually do, for some strange reason.

Comment: @animuson Okay, so you're saying that if I repost a bounty, that only NEW answers will be eligible for auto-assign at the end of the bounty period?

Comment: The answer is correct.  Sure, it is completely useless to you.  Hey, it is not like somebody didn't warn you about that.  Without any repro steps, a completely useless screenshot and not even a copy/paste of a build error, there isn't any way that anybody can tell that the answer is useless.  I don't rightly comprehend why anybody would ask a question that way.  It is, frankly, a dumb waste of time and rep, albeit that you entitled to waste it.  If you assume that a bounty is only ever going to get you posts from users that had the exact same problem you did then you are quite mistaken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The system naïvely assumes that the votes accurately reflect the usefulness of an answer (when, in truth, the votes only reflect the usefulness of an answer *as deemed by the voters*, and even that assumes the voters voted responsibly to begin with). So, since that answer had at least 2 upvotes, the system thinks the answer is useful and therefore awards it with the bounty.

The automatic assignment is in place as a safeguard for when the bounty setter forgets or is otherwise unable to award the bounty at the end of the bounty period, so users who *did* provide useful answers don't get shortchanged for their efforts. But, again, this all assumes that the votes do accurately reflect the usefulness of answers (which, granted, is mostly true in the majority of cases).

Comment: You can't award a bounty to a self-answer.

Comment: @animuson: You can. You just don't get back the reputation for it.

Comment: No you can't. That feature was removed in 2011.

Comment: @animuson: Oh. So there is no way to prevent a bounty from being auto-awarded to eligible answers (save from manually awarding it, I guess)?

Comment: @BoltClock Hmmm... that's interesting.. I am curious about the auto-assign... I've posted bounties before, but I guess I've been lucky as they've always had the desired effect: a good answer. So I don't know how long this has been a "feature". I assume there's a reason for it.. I can imagine people posting bounties to get an answer then withholding the bounty because they don't want to give up the rep... but in this case it is mildly frustrating... I'd love to give a bounty to someone who was able to help me, but frustrating that it was auto-assigned to someone who didn't.

Comment: In the last few hours of the bounty, a message told me it was going to be auto-assigned, and I had considered downvoting the answer to prevent it (it only had 2 votes at the time)... but that didn't feel like the right thing to do.. the answer may not have solved my problem.. but it wasn't bad or completely off-base...